# getopt_long don't return 0 when have flag set in struct option

Tags: c, getopt-long

I met a problem when using getopt_long in C. As is descripted, in the structure as follows:

```
struct option{ 
         const char *name; 
         int has_arg; 
         int *flag; 
         int val; 
};
```

If flag is set, getopt_long should return 0 and set *flag as val.
But in my code, getopt_long return val and *flag stay unchanged. The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<getopt.h>

int help;
int output;
int verbose;

const char *short_option = "ho:v";
const struct option long_options[] = {
    {"help", 0, &help, 'h'},
    {"output", 1, &output, 'o'},
    {"verbose", 0, &verbose, 'v'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

void print_help()
{
    printf("in option help: \n");
}

void print_output(char *content)
{
    printf("in option output: argument is %s\n",content);
}

void print_verbose()
{
    printf("in option verbose\n");

}

void print_args()
{
    printf("help is %d\n",help);
    printf("output is %d\n",output);
    printf("verbose is %c\n",verbose);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int next_option;
    while( (next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_option, long_options, NULL )) == 0)
    {
        printf("next_option is %c\n",next_option);
        print_args();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: _How_ do you run your program? What I want to know is if you start it with the long or the short options?

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour decribed. Everything works fine here, if using long options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), you will see that:

> **getopt_long()** and **getopt_long_only()** also return the option character when a short option is recognized. For a long option, they return val if flag is NULL, and 0 otherwise.

So if you use the short option when invoking your program, it will return that option character. For the function to behave as you want, you *must* use the long argument when invoking your program.